# Python function that calculates the weighted average amount between the dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of dictionaries and trying to create a function, that will add a new column, which will add a new column in each dictionary and calculate an order_delivery_cost weighted by price of the product_id.

```
q = [
    {"order_id": 987, "product_id": 4718, "price": 321, "order_delivery_cost": 600},
    {"order_id": 987, "product_id": 4719, "price": 654, "order_delivery_cost": 600},
    {"order_id": 987, "product_id": 4720, "price": 987, "order_delivery_cost": 600},
    {"order_id": 987, "product_id": 4725, "price": 110, "order_delivery_cost": 600}
]
```

Desired output:

| order_id | product_id | price | order_delivery_cost | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 987 | 4718 | 321 | 600 | 92.95 |
| 987 | 4719 | 654 | 600 | 189.38 |
| 987 | 4720 | 987 | 600 | 285.81 |
| 987 | 4725 | 110 | 600 | 31.85 |

Comment: How do you arrive at 92.95 for the first row when computing weighted delivery cost?  What is the logic behind this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`df.groupby().transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(q)

total_price = df.groupby('order_id')['price'].transform('sum')
df['new_column'] = (df['order_delivery_cost'] * df['price'] / total_price).round(2)
print(df)
```

You can also use lambda approach

```py
df['new_column'] = (df.apply(lambda row: row['order_delivery_cost'] * row['price'] 
                      / df[df['order_id'] == row['order_id']]['price']
                      .sum(), axis=1).round(2)) 
print(df)
```

---

```
   order_id  product_id  price  order_delivery_cost  new_column
0       987        4718    321                  600       92.95
1       987        4719    654                  600      189.38
2       987        4720    987                  600      285.81
3       987        4725    110                  600       31.85
```